# Want to show/hide control from ViewModel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I Want to show/hide control from ViewModel in wpf. But NotifyingProperty not working fine here is my code.

This is my control on design View

```
<ZuneWithCtrls_UserControls:SmallClock Visibility="{Binding IsProcessStart, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
                Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Top="150"/>
```

ViewMode

```
/// <summary>
    /// The NotifyingProperty for the IsProcessStart property.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly NotifyingProperty IsProcessStartProperty =
      new NotifyingProperty("IsProcessStart", typeof(bool), default(bool));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets IsProcessStart.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The value of IsProcessStart.</value>
    public bool IsProcessStart
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsProcessStartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsProcessStartProperty, value); }
    }
```

On Constructor of ViewModel I set

```
public AdvanceSearchViewModel()
    {
       IsProcessStart = false;
    }
```

And I am changing this property on button click command but it's not working. Plz help.
If this will work from Dependency property then who can i use Dependency property in ViewModel.

Ater Adding INotification

```
[ViewModel]
public class AdvanceSearchViewModel : PageViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AdvanceSearchViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public AdvanceSearchViewModel()
    {

        IsProcessStart = false;

    }

    //IsProcessStart
    private bool _IsProcessStart;
    public bool IsProcessStart
    {
        get { return _IsProcessStart; }
        set
        {
            _IsProcessStart = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsProcessStart");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged like this in your ViewModel

```
public class AdvanceSearchViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    .....
    Your Properties Here
    .....

    private bool _isProcessStart
    public bool IsProcessStart
    {
       get { return _isProcessStart; }
       set { 
             _isProcessStart = value; 
             OnPropertyChanged("IsProcessStart"); }
           }
}
```

For setting this property, just follow up to your ViewModel and set it like this -

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var isStarted = ViewModel.IsProcessStart;
    ViewModel.IsProcessStart = !isStarted;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mayur, I have tried this but not working in my case. Please check my updated code. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: After reading your comment. I tried it at my end and it works fine. Please also mention that how are you setting the value of "IsProcessStart"

Comment: I have posted 1. User control Code, 2. ViewModel Code (with IsProcessStart).

Comment: Visibility="{Binding IsProcessStart, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"

Comment: I am using Apex.dll Is there any issue with that.

Comment: No Idea about Apex.dll but for checking the same, I added a button in my sample application and set the value as shown in the edited version method MyButton_Click.

Comment: I think Issue with usercontrol visibility. I put my user control in canvas and apply property on canvas and working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use DependencyProperty in your ViewModel.

What you should do in your ViewModel is , implement INotifyPropertyChanged

[MSDN - How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have updated my post with INotifyProperyChanged but still not working. Plz help