# How to use a xaml control to show/hide other controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox in xaml which presents the user with 1, 2 and 3 as options.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbNoOfChoices" Text="{Binding Path = NoOfChoices, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
            <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox> 
        
    <Label x:Name="lblNo1" Content="Number 1" ></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxNo1" Text="{Binding Path = No1, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>

     <Label x:Name="lblNo2" Content="Number 2" ></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxNo2" Text="{Binding Path = No2, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
   
     <Label x:Name="lblNo3" Content="Number 3" ></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxNo3" Text="{Binding Path = No3, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

Two questions:

1. If 0 is selected then only label "Number 1" with associated textbox must be visible. If 1 is selected then only label "Number 1" and label "Number 2" with associated textboxes must be visible, etc. How do I do this?
2. Also have different equations being used depending on the combobox selection. Not sure how to extract the combobox selection to dictate which equation to use. Will a property by itself work?

public double NoOfChoices
{
get { return noOfChoices; }

```
        set
        {
            noOfChoices = value;
        }
    }
```

Will value above be the combobox selection?

Thanks.

Comment: Very first step could be a SelectedChanged event handler that executes all the code needed to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing a hidden WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994453/showing-a-hidden-wpf-window)

Comment: Are you sure your description in the question is correct?  Maybe you select 1 and it shows one label, select 2 and it shows 2 labels, select 3 and it shows all 3?  And what do these "different equations" look like?  How will they work.

Comment: @DotNetRussell - am thinking that just greying out the required controls might be easier than orchestrating their in/visibility.

Comment: @Andy, yes correct. It should be 1 for one label + textbox, 2 for 2 labels $ textboxes, etc. Each selection will trigger a different bunch of equations in the VM. I will look at doing this with SelectChanged event handler in the property bound to the combobox.

Comment: @Andy - I am doing matrix calcs. The size of the matrix depends on the combobox selection. If 1 then a 3x3, if 2 then a 4x4, if 3 then a 5x5.

Comment: I wouldn't do this in the ways suggested so far. You probably want a fixed size container so I'd blank inapplicable cells. I'd control this from the viewmodels. Bit tricky writing code on a phone tho.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"use a (..) control to show/hide other controls?"*

This seems an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). When you need to hide an edit control, set its Visibility property.

```
myEdit.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    // Visibility.Collapsed;
                    // Visibility.Visible;
```

You can do the same with its title label. When the components you want to hide are multiple, put them onto a panel container and hide the panel.

In WPF use observables, tags and bindings, ref these other SO questions,

[Elegant way to change control visibility in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783211/elegant-way-to-change-control-visibility-in-wpf)

[Want to show/hide control from ViewModel in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449115/want-to-show-hide-control-from-viewmodel-in-wpf)

.. which refers to [MSDN - How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: I will check out. Thank you. Am thinking of going the greyed out route rather than completely change visibility.

Comment: It looks better for individual textboxes.. for groups(multiple edits) I would hide things.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM solution that I can think of would be:

- Implement `ValueConverter` that converts an integer (or double) to `Visibility` and accepts a parameter value that when the converted value equals the parameter, returned value is `Visibility.Visible` and is `Visibility.Collapsed` in all other cases
- For all your labels (`lblNo1`, `lblNo2`, etc.) bind their `Visibility` to your  combobox `SelectedIndex` property with the earlier implemented value converter giving the respective parameter.

Let me know if it's clear to you. If not, I'll try to prepare some code.

### EDIT

New day, new energy, I've prepared some code for you.

You start with the implementation of the value converter in the following manner:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
public class IntEqualsToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts integer value to bool (is value equal to the parameter)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value determining the output</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">Target type onto which the value is converted (must be bool)</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">Determining value - if the value is equal to, output is true</param>
    /// <param name="culture">Culture info</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if the value is equal to the parameter</returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int determinant = 0;

        if (targetType != typeof(bool) && targetType != typeof(Object))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        if (parameter == null) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (parameter is int)
        {
            determinant = (int)parameter;
        }
        else if (!(parameter is string && int.TryParse(parameter as string, out determinant)))
            throw new ArgumentException("The converter parameter must be an integer or a string representing integer");

        return (int)value == determinant;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then, in your xaml, you add this converter as a resource, for my test it was simply a window, and I've added the `ValueConverter` implementation in my `local:` namespace:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntEqualsToBooleanConverter x:Key="IntToBoolConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Finally, your `ComboBox` and the items that you want to grey out may look like this - check the `IsEnabled` binding of the labels:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ComboBox Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="SelectionCombo">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 0" IsSelected="True" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2" />
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Label 0" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectionCombo, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
        <Label Content="Label 1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectionCombo, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
        <Label Content="Label 2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=SelectionCombo, Path=SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I hope it's what you're looking for. If you want the labels (or other controls) to completely disappear if not active, implement another value converter, where `Visibility` is the returning type and the last line of the `Convert` method would be:

```
return ((int)value == determinant) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```

And you'd bind to the `Visibility` property of the labels instead of `IsEnable`.

Comment: I assume I can make the controls greyed out using the above as well? Will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: In this case you'd need a `ValueConverter` with the same input but a `bool` output and bind the result to `IsEnabled` property of the controls you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using community mvvm toolkit.

Mainwindow

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ComboBox  DockPanel.Dock = "Top" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArrayOption}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                   />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="5"
                                 Columns="5"
                                 FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Num}"
                                 Grid.Column="1"/>

                        <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Fill="LightGray"
                                   Opacity=".4">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm greying the whole cell with a rectangle. You could instead bind visibility using a booleantovisibilityconverter.  You'd need an outer panel that remained or the cells would shift.  Another option is to hide the dockpanel but you'd need to write a booltoHide converter.

MainWindowViewModel

```
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        private CellVM[,] matrixCells = new CellVM[5, 5];

        [ObservableProperty]
        private List<CellVM> cells= new List<CellVM>();


        [ObservableProperty]
        private List<ArrayOptionVM> options = new List<ArrayOptionVM>
        {
            new ArrayOptionVM{ DisplayName = "1", MaxLimit= 3},
            new ArrayOptionVM{ DisplayName = "2", MaxLimit= 4},
            new ArrayOptionVM{ DisplayName = "3", MaxLimit= 5}
        };

        private ArrayOptionVM? selectedArrayOption;
        public ArrayOptionVM? SelectedArrayOption
        { get => selectedArrayOption; 
        set 
            {
                SetProperty(ref selectedArrayOption, value);
                setActiveCells(selectedArrayOption.MaxLimit);
            } 
        }

        private void setActiveCells(int maxLimit)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    matrixCells[x, y].IsActive = x < maxLimit && y < maxLimit;
                }
            }
        }
        public MainWindowViewModel() 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
                {
                    var cell = new CellVM { Description= $"{x},{y}" };
                    matrixCells[x, y] = cell;
                    cells.Add(cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Selection of an ArrayOptionVM drives what's greyed using a method called from a setter. This is going to slow that setter down by a teeny tiny amount so if you were doing significant processing you'd want a task on a different thread.

Each instance of CellVM is added to both a 2d array and a list for convenience in processing.

ArrayOptionVM defines the combo box items

```
public partial class ArrayOptionVM : ObservableObject
{
    public int MaxLimit = 3;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string displayName = string.Empty;

}
```

Maxlimit somewhat abstracts the maximum extent of active cells when one is chosen.

CellVM is the viewmodel behind each cell

```
public partial class CellVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string description = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int? num;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isActive;
}
```

Obviously, there's options here and definitely room for improvement.

Here's a version of mainwindow binding visibility.

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ComboBox  DockPanel.Dock = "Top" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArrayOption}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                   />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="5"
                                 Columns="5"
                                 FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Num}"
                                 Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Gosh Andy, thanks so much. Much to digest and work through.