# How do I get a certain row within a wpf datagrid, which is formed by DataGridTextColumns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got a datagrid of 3 rows.
The datagrid is generated by a class(datagrid.class) which writes three columns a time.
  This process performs 3 times so that'a 9-cell datagrid.
Please noted that it's formed by columns. 
And I have a combobox of 3 comboboxItems.
The combobox_SelectionChanged method is wanted to be set like this:

```
private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (ComboOpticalInput.SelectedIndex == 2)
// Show 3 all rows,1st row gets grayish      
sentense 1;
    else if (ComboOpticalInput.SelectedIndex == 1)
    // Show 3 all row, 2nd row gets grayish 
    sentense 2;
       else
       // Show 3 all row, 3rd row  gets grayish 
       sentense 3;
}
```

And my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="DataGrid1" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="option" Width="5*" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="DGOP1" Binding="{Binding option}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1" Width="3*" x:Name="DGOP2" Binding="{Binding PValue}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2" Width="2*" x:Name="DGOP3" Binding="{Binding QValue}">
                
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Datagrid.cs :

```
namespace myq

{public class datagrid
  {
    public string option { get; set; }
    public double PValue { get; set; }
    public string QValue { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Whole XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="myq.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myq"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="600">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <ComboBox Name="Combobox1" SelectedIndex="-1" SelectionChanged="Combobox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem>Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Item #3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="DataGrid1" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="option" Width="5*" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="DGOP1" Binding="{Binding option}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1" Width="3*" x:Name="DGOP2" Binding="{Binding PValue}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2" Width="2*" x:Name="DGOP3" Binding="{Binding QValue}">                    
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.cs:

```
namespace myq
{

  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
  public ObservableCollection<datagrid> FirstProperties { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FirstProperties = new()
        {
            new datagrid()
            {
                option = "Short",
                PValue = 550,
                QValue = "[nm]",
            },
            new datagrid()
            {
                option = "Long",
                PValue  = 3800,
                QValue = "[nm]",
            },
            new datagrid()
            {   option = "Medium",
                PValue  = 6,
                QValue = "[]"
            }
        };
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = FirstProperties;
    }

    private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window win1 = new Window();
        if (Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            win1.Show();

        else if (Combobox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            win1.Close();
        else;
    }
}
```

}

My Question is : How do i write sentense 1?
I searched for quite some time didn't find a solution.

I googled this, many of the answers are about selected datagrid rows.

I don't need to select any of the row.The interact within comboboxItem selection and one row of the datagrid is set.

Also I tried sth like:

```
DataGrid1.row[1].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Grey);
```

and the return is:

```
>"datagrid" does not contain a definition for "row"
```

Thanks for taking concerns to here. Any hint will be appreacited.

Comment: For one thing, it's not very clear what you are actually asking?  I *think* you are asking "how do I make a specific row in a datagrid appear differently, based on the selection in a combobox?"

Secondly, you need to format your code correctly as this makes it very hard to read - either indent all those lines with 4 leading spaces, or use backtick - "`". (you seem to have added some text as a code block, but that isn't code so not sure how/why)

Comment: Yeah,you understand it correctly. I'll edit my code,thanks

Comment: Sorry for the 1st time using stackoverflow, I edited already. Is there a way that I can get the 1st/2nd/3rd row of my datagrid? If yes, will there be a way to turn the whole row(or the elements within) to greyish? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is : How do i write sentense 1?

You don't. What I've learned about WPF is to stay away from writing code in favour of using bindings and other mechanisms that WPF provides.

To solve your problem you can basically do, what I've described in another thread here: [How to use a xaml control to show/hide other controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095589/how-to-use-a-xaml-control-to-show-hide-other-controls/75099362#75099362)

In your case you can perhaps modify the `ValueConverter` to return `Visibility` instead of `bool`.
Make sure you name your `ComboBox` and then, when generating your `DataGrid` rows, you add binding to each row's `Visibility` property in a similar way that I've described for the `IsEnabled` of the `Label`s.

**EDIT:**
I've done some search and prototyping and this is what I've found.
Basically, what I've written earlier is not that straightforward when coming to `DataGrid`. But, I've developed a solution for you still hugely based on my initial concept.
With the code you've provided I'd do the following:

- first implement a multivalue converter wee need to compare two values where both are kind of dynamic:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int[]), typeof(Visibility))]
public class IntEqualsToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Visibility) && targetType != typeof(Object))
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The target must be a Visibility");
        return values.Length == 2 && (int)values[0] == (int)values[1] ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

- then you need to alter your `datagrid` class (by the way, try not to "reuse" the typenames, give a meaningful name to the class) so it holds the combobox reference, row id and creates the binding:

```
public class MyDatagridDataType
{
    public MyDatagridDataType(int rowId)
    {
        this.RowId = rowId;
    }

    public int RowId { get; private set; }

    public string? Option { get; set; }
    public double PValue { get; set; }
    public string? QValue { get; set; }
}
```

- then you slightly alter your `MainWindow` constructor, to you provide the `DataContext` and give the id to each row that corresponds to the combobox selected index:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    var firstProperties = new MyDatagridDataType[]
    {
        new MyDatagridDataType(0)
        {
            Option = "Short",
            PValue = 550,
            QValue = "[nm]",
        },
        new MyDatagridDataType(1)
        {
            Option = "Long",
            PValue = 3800,
            QValue = "[nm]",
        },
        new MyDatagridDataType(2)
        {
            Option = "Medium",
            PValue = 6,
            QValue = "[]"
        }
    };

    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = firstProperties;
}
```

- and finally, in your `DataGrid`, you define `RowStyle` as following (you bind the row's `Visibility` property to `Combobox1`'s `SelectedItem` and row's `RowId` with multivalue converter):

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Combobox1" Path="SelectedIndex" />
                    <Binding Path="RowId" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

- don't forget to add window's resource with the miltivalue converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IntEqualsToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ValueToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

It works for me.

What we learned here is:

- how to use bindings
- how to set the properties on `DataGrid` row
- how to implement and use `IMultiValueConverter`

Comment: Get parts of your solutions,thanks. But how do I get the description of a certain row of my datagrid(I uploaded it in the edit )? Something like DataGrid1.row[1] is not working.

Comment: When your class generates the `DataGrid`, you add the bindings to the rows in code behind. Try to think in the way that it isn't you that you want to tell your rows what to do, it's the other way round - the rows themselves bind to some other elements. If you have problems, is it possible that you share some parts of your grid generation code so I can tra to replicate your problem?

Comment: And I see I got a downvote from someone. I wonder why. Knowing the reason for that would help me improve my future answers.

Comment: I‘m a new member of stakoverflow, I don't have permissions to vote, I tried vote up,tho. Again, thanks Mike. I'll update my grid generation code.

Comment: Thanks @rookieqt, no problem. If you won't get it working, let me know, I'll try to prepare an example code for you.

Comment: I think the reason downvotes do not require a comment is because some people are inclined to revenge downvoting.  I'm not sure though.   I know I pointed out a flaw in someone's answer ( thought I was reasonably polite ) and they downvoted like 10 of my answers. Because there's a mechanism detects that and stops serial downvoting.  Maybe an answer which mainly references some other answer is more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: I just realised another possible reason for a downvote. Isn't a value converter code? In this case very specific code which probably isn't getting so much re use. But that code is somehow better in a converter?

Comment: Whold codes uploaded. My grid generation code is set in: Datagrid.cs and MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: @Andy - ValueConverter is quite specific code but it gets user over and over in this particular application. So you get quite a lot reuse of it. There are two answers already, both introducing value converters. And personally, I don't know any other method, I use value converters quite often, that's why I proposed this solution. I'm curious if there is another way.

Comment: @Mike there are a few ways I can think of offhand. The first piece of code in my answer does not use a converter. Viewmodel code could return a bool. There is no converter in my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095589/how-to-use-a-xaml-control-to-show-hide-other-controls/75099362#75099362

Comment: @Andy - if you need to control the `IsEnabled` property and you want to control it from the `SelectionChanged` than yes, you don't need value converters. I don't use this method, I don't think it's elegant enough for WPF. The OP wanted the rows to disappear in the initial version of the question, hence mine struggle to control the  `Visibility` property and not `IsEnabled`. And I've read your answer after I've finished working on mine, I see they are duplicate in certain part.

Comment: @Mike I followed your steps, implemented your multivalue converter, rewrite datagrid class, altered  MainWindow constructor, defined RowStyle, added window's resource with the miltivalue converter. 
 And there's a exception:  

System.InvalidCastException:“Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Int32'.”

Comment: Do you know which line of code throws that exception? If it's in the multivalue converter, probably you're providing an object as a parameter instead of the object's property that contains the value.

Comment: @Mike
It thorws at this :------------------------
 
return values.Length == 2 && (int)values[0] == (int)values[1] ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;  --------------------------------------------

and the exception is :  -----------------------------------------

System.InvalidCastException:“Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Int32'.”

Comment: I suspect you either have some typos (which is impossible since you've been copy/paste the code I've provided, right) in `RowId` property, or you're not binding to `SelectedIndex` of the combo box and rather `SelectedItem`. What helps in this case is setting a breakpoint in the multiconverter code and checking which objects are passed as `values` array. Can you check that for me?

Comment: @Mike  
You're right. There are some typos in public class MyDatagridDataType. I can run it now.-------------------------------------------------------
But there's one point I do not express clear. The Effect( Each time I select a comboboxItem, only 1 row shows up) is not the same as i wished(I want all 3 rows to show,each time one of them is gray).---------------------------------------------------------------
I edit my descriptions of sentense 1~3 now. I'll see what I can do before any of your comments.      ---------------------------------Anyway,thanks for your through help.

Comment: @rookieqt - I understand your requirement. I'll leave it as a "homework" for you. What you have to realise is that right now you're effecting the `Visibility` property of every row of your data grid while you want to effect the `IsEnabled` property (which is a `bool` and not `Visibility`). To help you, I'll give you a couple of hints - you need to create another multiconverter, that takes two values (combo box selected item Id and the data grid row Id) and return `true` if those two are equal. Also in the styling of the data grid the setter property should be `IsEnabled`.

Comment: @Mike 
    It's done now. Thanks so much for your detialed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

When they were designing WPF they took some fundamental design choices.

One design choice was to favour binding over the VB6 pattern devs used of building controls and adding them into comboboxes or gridviews.

It is not particularly obvious how you get at a row out a datagrid in code. The designers did not envision that to be the way devs would work with rows.

You could do this in code:

```
    private void ComboInput_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastRowIndex > -1)
        {
            var lastrow = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lastRowIndex);
            lastrow.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        var row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ComboInput.SelectedIndex);
        row.IsEnabled = false;
        lastRowIndex = ComboInput.SelectedIndex;
    }
    int lastRowIndex = -1;
```

Here my datagrid is called dg ( obviously ).

This approach relies on the selected index of the combobox being the same as the index of the row in the datagrid you want to gray. I am just using IsEnabled here but you could do other things with that row once you have a reference if you prefer.

You could use a binding and converter usually to set a value on some property. You need both the index of the row considered and the value of whatever is set in the combobox. You'd need a multibinding and multiconverter.

It would also be good if this multiconverter was at least somewhat re-usable.

We also need some way to get at that row, which would be to use rowstyle.

Bringing all that together my xaml would look like:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dg" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              AlternationCount="10000">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:IsMultiNotEqualConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="AlternationIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" ElementName="ComboInput"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Alternationindex is being used here to give the row index.

The multiconverter looks like:

```
public class IsMultiNotEqualConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !values[0].Equals(values[1]);
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
    private static IsMultiNotEqualConverter _converter = null;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => _converter ??= new IsMultiNotEqualConverter();
}
```

Which can be used without declaring it as a resource because it's a markupextension as well as a converter.

That multi binding and converter could instead be used in a datatrigger to apply a style to your particular row.

This isn't super complicated but it's also not super simple and you can perhaps see why it's more usual to work with bound collections of viewmodels which can have logic encapsulated in code within them and bind properties directly to them.

Comment: I would vote up but as a new memeber of stackoverflow I don't have the permission yet. I'll try your method(way) and see what I can do. Many thanks.

Comment: @rookieqt you can mark an answer for your question. I think you will see a check mark next to each possible answer. If one solves it then you check that. If there are several answers proposed and your question is solved 
you check the one solves it best.

Comment: Noted and thanks. That muliticonverter is a bit hard for me now. I'll see what I can accomplish. 
By the way, all codes upload now.

Comment: I like `MarkupExtension` on the converter implementation.